# Regex: Extracting numbers only until first space

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have below data:

> #1314515 22-09-2021

And need to extract only numbers and not date as below:

> 1314515

Have tried below Regex combinations but does not work:

```
[\s0-9]+
\s[0-9]+
```

Please help with correct combination.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use regex and [**`pd.Series.str.extract`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```py
df['col'] = df['col'].str.extract('(\d+)(?=\s)')
```

To convert to integer:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].str.extract('(\d+)(?=\s)').astype(int)
```

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/uUg7TC/1).

Answer (score 1):

We can use `str.extract` as follows:

```py
df["num"] = df["col"].str.extract(r'^#(\d+)')
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `[\s0-9]+` will match 1+ occurrences of either a digits or a whitespace char and has no boundaries for your desired match, matching too much.

You could start the match with no digits, capture 1+ digits and then match a space

```
^\D*(\d+)\s
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/H42cKP/1)

For example:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].str.extract(r'^\D*(\d+)\s')
```

**col** value:

```
1314515
```

---

Or you might also match digits not surrounded by hyphens using negative lookarounds (which would also match only digits without a following whitspace char)

```
(?<!-)\b(\d+)\b(?!-)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wgoBIs/1)

For example:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].str.extract(r'(?<!-)\b(\d+)\b(?!-)')
```

**col** value:

```
1314515
```